# How can I realtime receive message from server

Tags: sockets, lua, coronasdk

First, please look at my code below.

```
local function receiveData( )
    l = client:receive()
    print(l)
    return l
end

local refNum = receiveData()

local function endTurn( )
    waitText = display.newText("Opponent Turn",centerX,allY*.1,native.systemFont,30)
    local passer = receiveData()
    if passer ~= nil then
        takeTurn()
    end
end
```

What I want to do is displaying waitText on screen but I faced the obstruction because waitText will not appear until passer get received data first. So, I would like to know how to display waitText while wait for received data.

I will appreciate any advice, Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to do two things:

1. Set a timeout on your socket via the `settimeout(seconds)` function on the socket object. This is documented [here](http://w3.impa.br/~diego/software/luasocket/tcp.html). Note that you will have to then check the error code when you use `receive`, as it could be `timeout` to indicate that nothing was available for read in the given time.
2. Setup a timer function to continue reading the socket at regular interval, until the data arrives

Something like:

```
client:settimeout(0.01) -- 10 ms

local function receiveData( )
    l,e = client:receive()
    print(l)
    return l,e
end

function checkReceive()
    local passer, err = receiveData()
    if passer ~= nil then
        takeTurn()
    else
        timer.performWithDelay(100, checkReceive) -- repeat the check in 100 ms
    end
end

local function endTurn( )
    waitText = display.newText("Opponent Turn",centerX,allY*.1,native.systemFont,30)
    checkReceive() -- returns in 10ms if nothing available, and will be called 
                   -- automatically every 100ms until something arrives
end
```

The `seconds` can have millisecond precision but actual precision that can be honored will vary by system.

Comment: Excellent. I notice you have enough points to upvote, if you think it should be improved first please post comment and I will fix.

Answer (score 0):

May be it is underneath other object? try waitText:toFront()

Comment: I think It's not underneath because when I commented passer line, the message appeared.